# How can I centralize my Database in my Application in Wpf?

Tags: database, sockets, ms-access

I am Working on a small College Project. In which there will be a server module and client module. and the server is going to perform some functions that will affect the client. I came up with sockets which can work on Lan. I am using sockets with UDP. and its working all good. the problem is that i have to develop both the module in one project. so when the application will run the database which is MS access. will be in two Different computers and the data recorded will be different. so how can i centralize  the database for both. Its a college project so there is only one Server and one client.

Any Suggestions ?

Thankz in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to think of your architecture differently. Consider when there are many clients and just one server (even if you only ever run one client). Now you can see that the data storage has to be on the server as that is the only place it can exist.

Commonly you would build application like this

- Client Application
- Client Data access
- Network library
- Server Data access
- DB on server

Comment: Thank you for your response. Il find some more stuff on Accessing Databse on network that will help i guess right ?